# Section headers next to items in SectionedRecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement [SectionedRecyclerView](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) everything works perfectly. I would only like section headers to be next to items, not above,
 like it's shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNBOB.png) and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: not possible with a recycler view

Comment: @Roy, with **Sectioned**RecyclerView if it's not possible even with this what should I use than?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy or quick solution to this.

a) If you just want to show the header section next to your items you can have a look at [`RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html) to **just draw** the headers next to your items. You won't be able to click on them or some other interaction, as it is litterally only *drawn* there. Just a drawing. No View. (Can't emphasize this enough)

b) If you want actual RecyclerView support for this layout, you will have to create your own LayoutManager. Neither LinearLayoutManager nor GridLayoutManager has support for such behavior. This is probably by far the most difficult approach.

c) If you want to get hacky you could return a different view type for your first item of every section, inflating the section header along with the first item or try working with a GridLayoutManager, and using [`SpanSizeLookup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup.html) to align your elements, working with dummy (empty) views filling in the blanks below your section headers.

d) As a last alternative you can just inflate the whole section as one item, which would only be recommended if every section has very few items, since it negates the idea of a recyclerview. You can even inflate recyclerviews within the recyclerview if you want, although keep in mind that they would not actually be "recycling" any views since their whole content gets added at once (when the section is visible)

Comment: Thank you for awesome answer, I am probably going to try to create my own LayoutManager. I also want section headers to move along items as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoFzE.png) and I suppose that it isn't possible with ItemDecoration, is it?

Comment: @F.Korf you just draw. what and where is up to you, so it is possible with decorations. Probably still easier than creating your own layout manager